# get total working hour based of day of the week

Tags: mysql

I want to check if employee's daily working hour is less than total working hour assigned.

For example employee #1 are assigned to work :

```
Day | Total working hours
mon | 10
tue | 10
wed | 10
thu | 10
fri | 10
sat | 0
sun | 0
```

I have total working hour of employee #1 as below :

```
Start               | End                         | Total Hours Worked
2018-07-02 00:28:29 | 2018-07-02 04:12:17         | 3.72 
2018-07-05 00:26:20 | 2018-07-05 05:03:23         | 4.62 
2018-07-12 00:27:35 | 2018-07-12 10:21:08         | 9.88
```

The problem I'm facing is to know which day of the week to check the total working hour based on date. e.g. 2018-07-02 is monday so the total working hour employee should work is 10 hours however the total hour worked by the employee is only 3.72. Hence for 2018-07-02 employee has not fullfill total working hour assigned.

The expected query result should return :

```
Short Working Hour Date 
2018-07-02
2018-07-05
2018-07-12
```

Appreciate any help from you guys. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Strawberry no i didnt. Still figuring

Comment: @Strawberry you have any idea?

Comment: Yeah, look at the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it refering the manual. But it looks messy.

```
SELECT
    start,
    end,
    total_hours_worked
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DATE(start), DATE(end)
having CASE 
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(MIN(start))=1 and total_hours_worked < 0   THEN 1 
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(MIN(start))=2 and total_hours_worked < 10  THEN 1 
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(MIN(start))=3 and total_hours_worked < 10  THEN 1 
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(MIN(start))=4 and total_hours_worked < 10  THEN 1 
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(MIN(start))=5 and total_hours_worked < 10  THEN 1 
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(MIN(start))=6 and total_hours_worked < 10  THEN 1 
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(MIN(start))=7 and total_hours_worked < 0   THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're after, so here's an incomplete solution...

```
DROP TABLE employee_assignments;

CREATE TABLE employee_assignments
(day CHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,total_working_hours INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO employee_assignments VALUES
('mon',10),
('tue',10),
('wed',10),
('thu',10),
('fri',10),
('sat',0),
('sun',0);

DROP TABLE timesheet;

CREATE TABLE timesheet
(start DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,end  DATETIME NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO timesheet VALUES
('2018-07-02 00:28:29','2018-07-02 04:12:17'),
('2018-07-05 00:26:20','2018-07-05 05:03:23'),
('2018-07-12 00:27:35','2018-07-12 10:21:08');

SELECT t.*
     , (TIME_TO_SEC(t.end)-TIME_TO_SEC(t.start))/3600 n 
     , a.*
  FROM timesheet t
  JOIN employee_assignments a
    ON a.day = DATE_FORMAT(t.start,'%a');

+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-----+---------------------+
| start               | end                 | n      | day | total_working_hours |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-----+---------------------+
| 2018-07-02 00:28:29 | 2018-07-02 04:12:17 | 3.7300 | mon |                  10 |
| 2018-07-05 00:26:20 | 2018-07-05 05:03:23 | 4.6175 | thu |                  10 |
| 2018-07-12 00:27:35 | 2018-07-12 10:21:08 | 9.8925 | thu |                  10 |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------+-----+---------------------+
```